# How to install FFMPEG into GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

**How to install FFMPEG in Google Cloud Shell. is that possible?**

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQapw.png)

sorry for my bad language

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using FFMPEG on Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147585/using-ffmpeg-on-google-cloud-platform)

Answer (score 4):

You can install FFmpeg on Cloud Shell using the following commands. However, your Cloud Shell machine is ephemeral and no system-wide change will persist beyond session end.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

[Customize Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/configuring-cloud-shell#environment_customization)